# JQuery UI autocomplete menu to be reset on mouseout if user wants to fill this particular textbox later

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

On mouseover, the list displays, and when the user clicks on one item of the list, the textbox is supposed to be populated with the selected item. The autocomplete shows up on mouse over. But if the user changes his/her mind and decides to fill in the textbox later, the mouseout should close the menu. This is what mouseout is doing as well - but it is currently preventing the user from selecting something from the autocomplete menu if he/she wants to fill it immediately. What would also be cool if the user accidentally selected the wrong item and wants the menu to reappear onmouseover to correct the selection.
Any suggestions welcome.Thanks.

JFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KarlosFanta/bc9SR/3/

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = [ "Battleship", "Tank", "Bazooka"];
$( "#lst" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags,
minLength: 0
    }).mouseover(function() {
        $(this).autocomplete("search");

//if mouse hovers away from the menu and the textbox- only then the mouseout function should fire
//this mouseout below is preventing me from selecting the menu: 
   }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).autocomplete( "close" );
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="lst" >

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, Demo link http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/bc9SR/4/

```
        $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
        "Battelship",
        "Abracadabra"
        ];
        $( "#lst" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        minLength: 0
            }).mouseover(function() {
                $(this).autocomplete("search");

/*  if mouse hovers away from the menu and the textbox- 
    only then the mouseout function should fire
this mouseout below is preventing me from selecting the menu:
*/
           }).mouseout(function() {
            var isHovered = $('ul.ui-autocomplete:hover').length > 0
            console.log(isHovered)
            if(!isHovered){
            $(this).autocomplete( "close" );
            };


        });

            setInterval(function(){
                var isinputHovered = $('#lst:hover').length > 0
    var isHovered = $('ul.ui-autocomplete:hover').length > 0
    if(!isHovered && !isinputHovered) {
       $('#lst').autocomplete( "close" );
    }

}, 200);
        });
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly in Google Chrome, but unfortunately not in my  favourite Mozilla Firefox :-(

Comment: How can one make the list appear on page load or on page refresh?